# How to find out the probability of uniformly distributed random variable by looking at the random variables only?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This question is from problem 4.1 of the book *Introduction to Probability*, 2nd edition":

> If $X$ is a random variable that is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $1$. Find the PDF of $\sqrt{|x|}$ and the PDF of $-\ln(|x|)$. The solution of to the PDF of $\sqrt{|x|}$ states that $P(-y^2 \le X \le y^2) = y^2$. (I think I may be able to figure out how to get the second PDF if I understand the first PDF).

My question is that the probability of a uniformly distributed PDF (supposed discrete) is

$$pX(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 1/(b+a-1), &\text{if $x = a, a+1, \dotsc, b$;} \\
 0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
How then we can figure out, without any derivation from $1/(b+a-1)$ (the value of $pX(x)$) to get the final probability of $Y (PY(y))$ by only looking at the values of $x$? $(P(\{X=x\}) = pX(x)$ by definition, and $P(\{X=x\})$ cannot be $x$, for it is in the form of $1/(b+a-1))$.

Comment: There are many books titled "Introduction to Probability"; can you please edit your post to include the author(s)?

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim\mathrm{Unif}[-1,1]$ then
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\sqrt{|X|}\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(|X|\leqslant t^2)\\ &= \mathbb P(X\geqslant t^2,X<0) + \mathbb P(X\leqslant -t^2,X>0)\\
&= 2\mathbb P(X\leqslant t^2,X>0) \text{ (by symmetry)}\\
&= 2\int_0^{t^2}\frac12\ \mathsf ds, \\
&= t^2
\end{align}
from which the density of $\sqrt{X}$ is $t^2\cdot\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t)$.

If $Y = -\log(|X|)$ then
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(-\log|X|\leqslant t)\\
&= \mathbb P(|X|\geqslant e^{-t})\\
&= \mathbb P(X\geqslant e^{-t}, X>0) + \mathbb P(X\leqslant -e^{-t},X<0)\\
&= 2\int_{e^{-t}}^1 \frac12\ \mathsf ds\\
&= (1-e^{-t})\cdot 1_{(0,\infty)}(t),
\end{align}
so that $|X|$ has exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

Comment: $\mathbb P(|X|\geqslant -2t^2)=1$ for any $t$.

Comment: Thanks. The core of my question is actually on how you know the integration is on 1/2? Is it 1/(1-(-1)+1) ? of the discrete uniform random variable format?

Comment: @NCh Thanks, I have corrected my error